# Eigendecomposition of $(a^\top X a)X - Xaa^\top X$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd, matrix-analysis

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonzero vector, $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be positive definite. What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $(a^\top X a) X - Xaa^\top X$?

Comment: Presumably $a$ is a column vector and you mean $(a^\top X a) X - X a a^\top X$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That’s right. I modified the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wlog use an orthonormal basis where $a$ is a multiple of the first basis element: $a = t e_1$.
Write $X$ in block form as $$ X = \pmatrix{x_1 & X_2\cr X_2^\top & X_3\cr}$$
Then
$$ (a^\top X a) X - X a a^\top X =  t^2 \pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 0 & x_1 X_3 - X_2^\top X_2}$$
One eigenvalue is $0$, the others are $t^2$ times the eigenvalues of 
$x_1 X_3 - X_2^\top X_2$.

Note that the latter is a rank-$1$ perturbation of $x_1 X_3$, and the [Matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) might be useful.

EDIT: By that lemma,

$$ \det(x_1 X_3 - X_2^\top X_2 - \lambda I) = (1 + X_2 (x_1 X_3 - \lambda I)^{-1} X_2^\top) \det(x_1 X_3 - \lambda I)$$
so if $X_2 (x_1 X_3 - \lambda I)^{-1} X_2^\top = -1$ then $\lambda$ must be an eigenvalue of $x_1 X_3 - X_2^\top X_2$.  If $v_j$ are an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $x_1 X_3$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\mu_j$, 
that condition is
$$ \sum_j (\mu_j - \lambda)^{-1} (X_2 v_j)^2 = -1$$

Comment: What can we say about the relationships between eigenvalues of $(a^\top X a) X - Xaa^\top X$ and those of $X$?